# Tangents to a Cubic

Tags: geometry

Suppose $y=ax^3 + bx^2  + cx + d$ is a cubic (so that $a\ne 0$). Show that every point in the plane lies on at least one tangent to this cubic.

Comment: Did you try something at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(u,v)$ an arbitrary point. The equation of the tangent to the cubic in $(x_0,y_0)$ is $y-(ax_0^3+bx_0^2+cx_0+d)=(3ax_0^2+2bx_0+c)(x-x_0).$ We need to show that there exists $x_0$ such that  $v-(ax_0^3+bx_0^2+cx_0+d)=(3ax_0^2+2bx_0+c)(u-x_0).$ Writing this equality as an equation in $x_0$ we get

$$2ax_0^3+(b-3au)x_0^2-2bux_0+v-cu-d=0.$$ Since any cubic equation always has at least one solution, we have that the given point $(u,v)$ lies in one tangent to the cubic.